# How do I add #![feature(***)] to another crate's attributes without forking the crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Every time I see an error like:

> error: associated constants are experimental (see issue #29646)
>   ... 
>   = help: add #![feature(associated_consts)] to the crate attributes to enable 
>   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

I fork the crate and add the feature to the crate attributes and then replace the dependency in my Cargo.toml:

```
[replace."bitflags:1.0.0"]
git = "https://github.com/boehm-s/bitflags"
rev = "bb2afce"
```

Is there a way to get rid of these errors without forking crates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I add #![feature(***)] to another crate's attributes without forking the crate?

You **don't**. You cannot change another crate without... changing it.

You are using an old nightly compiler; **update it**. If you are using a nightly compiler, it's your responsibility to keep it up-to-date. If you don't know why you have a nightly compiler, switch to a stable compiler.

---

This can only occur if:

1. You are using a nightly compiler. If you weren't, you wouldn't get the suggestion to add the attribute, it'd be a hard error.
2. You are using a crate that relies on a feature that has not been stabilized in your version of the compiler and thus requires the attribute to enable it.
3. The feature has been stabilized in a newer version of Rust and thus the crate no longer needs to have the attribute itself.

---

For this example, you can read [the crates changelog](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/bitflags/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100):

> ### 1.0.0
>
> - **[breaking change]** Macro now generates associated constants (#24)
> - **[breaking change]** Minimum supported version is Rust 1.20, due to usage of associated constants

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a nightly compiler because I will use crates that relies on non-stable features, and it doesn't only concern the `associated_consts` feature, this was just an example

Comment: @boehm_s right, which is why I put the stuff specific to `associated_consts` at the end of the answer — all the rest of it is generic.

Answer (score 6):

Associated constants were stabilized recently in Rust 1.20; this error should disappear without any code changes if you upgrade your Rust compiler.

In addition to [`[replace]` and `[patch]`](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#overriding-dependencies), there's also the option of using [`.cargo/config`](http://doc.crates.io/config.html) to [override a dependency locally](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#overriding-with-local-dependencies) without changing `Cargo.toml`.